# Launching WPF app from Silverlight OOB

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, com

Is it possible to launch and (less important) control a WPF application from a Silverlight OOB app? Would I need to create an Automation Server for the WPF app. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using silverlight 4+, using an out of browser **trusted** silverlight application, you have access to COM interop.

For example, you can use COM interop to launch an application like excel, like [here](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/graphics/native-apis-and-services/com-object-access-in-trusted-applications) which allows not only launching, but controlling and populating information back and forth.

For your WPF application, you would likely need to create a COM library and installer for the users to run.  After that, any trusted silverlight application could access this library in order to pass commands to launch the application as well as take control or handle events in the WPF application.

See a similar example of writing a COM wrapper for launching applications [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/HyperlinkExec03012007191054PM/HyperlinkExec.aspx).  This example launches the application from a web browser, but the idea is easily the same for your silverlight application.